# Mock an attribute to intercept a call to its own method inside a class method

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

How can I ensure `self.a.set_name` is called with the right parameters and values? I would like to patch the object instead of each method individual because there're 15 of them.

Here is one of things I've tried which fails with `AssertionError: Expected 'set_name' to be called once. Called 0 times.`:

```py
# src/resources.py
from package_a import ClassA


class MyClassB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None

    def get_a(self, name: str):
        self.a = ClassA()
        self.a.set_name(name=name)
```

```py
# test/test_resources.py
from src.resources import MyClassB
from unittest import mock

class TestClassB:
    def test_get_a(self):
        b = MyClassB()
        # with mock.patch("src.resources.package_a.ClassA") as mocked_a: # this also doesn't work
        with mock.patch.object(b, "a") as mocked_a:
            b.get_a(name="test")
            mocked_a.set_name.assert_called_once_with(name="test")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not patching the correct object. In `MyClassB.get_a`, you first create a brand new `ClassA` object and then call `set_name` on that object. That means that you have to mock the `set_name` method on `ClassA`:

```
class TestClassB(TestCase):
    def test_get_a(self):
        b = MyClassB()
        with mock.patch.object(ClassA, "set_name") as mocked_a:
            print(ClassA.set_name)
            b.get_a(name="test")
            mocked_a.assert_called_once_with(name="test")
```

Comment: You're right. Is there a way to mock `self.a` inside `get_a` to avoid having to mock each individual method? There're 15 them...

Comment: I've tried  `with mock.patch("src.resources.package_a.ClassA") as mocked_a:` but the assertion fails with "AssertionError: Expected 'set_name' to be called once. Called 0 times."